# UIWebView not work for file:///private/var/..../(myapp).app/www/index.html

Tags: ios, uiwebview, bundle

When I using code below to open an embedded html file. it cannot trigger the delegate : [ 
- webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:];

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///private/var/..../(myapp).app/www/index.html"];

NSMutableURLRequest *urlReq = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWith:url
                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                              timeoutInterval: 60.0f];

[webview loadRequest:urlReq];
```

How can I get this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its your local machine path, not the simulator/iOS path. For iOS, there are only two directories for file resources:

- NSBundle
- Document directory

In your case, your www folder is in Bundle folder so, try this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"]];
```

Comment: the path is come from NSBundle class, the actual path point to myapp.app/www/ .  It's only not work from iOS8.